# Fabric NDK crash reporting for android studio 2.3+

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, crashlytics-android

I am trying to configure fabric NDK bug reporting. I used instructions [provided](https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/ndk.html) by fabric.

I added NDK dependency to my cradle file.

```
dependencies {
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-ndk:1.1.6@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}

crashlytics {
    enableNdk true
 // according to documentation if I use grade plugin 2.2+ (I use 2.3.3) I can commit setting androidNdkOut and androidNdkLibsOut
 }
```

I compile project using this command

```
./gradlew crashlyticsUploadSymbolsRelease
```

But all my crash reports look like this one:

```
Crashed: part.of.my.package.name|
0  ???                            0x0 (Missing)
```

Does anyone know how to correctly setup crashlytics NDK?

Thank you.

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Do you have external libraries which are creating symbols?

Comment: Hello @MikeBonnell yes I link one dynamic and one static library to my project (both compiled together with my code) and I see two *.cSYM files under app/build/fabric/release/csyms directory

Comment: Sorry for the delay. That should be fine - what's the output after running uploadSymbols? Do you see the confirmation of the upload or any other output?

Comment: @MikeBonnell Hi Mike, I have exactly same issue as OP, could you please provide more info about what to look at in the logs? In my case I have `15:22:47.644 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] :FiosMobile:crashlyticsUploadSymbolsMarketDebug (Thread[Task worker Thread 7,5,main]) completed. Took 2.546 secs.` in gradle output, how do I understand if the symbols are actually uploaded? Some specific message in the logs? Some place in Fabric Dashboard?

Comment: Those logs to me indicated that the upload was successful. What do you see for your crashes?  The same one line crash report?

Comment: @MikeBonnell yes all the crashes are the same.

Crashed:part.of.my.package.name|
SIGABRT -6 0x0000000000002a73 (and this one line from description when I press </> Raw Text button)

Comment: Gotcha, can you please email support(at)fabric(dot)io and reference this thread and ask for me so I can dive in more with you?

Comment: @MikeBonnell sure

Comment: @MikeBonnell I have also emailed you from pa*.d*@o*.v*.com if you don't mind.